# Laravel Query ((Key1=A and Key2=B) or (Key1=B and Key2=A)) and Key3=C

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I build a query in the following way for basic query.

```
// e.g. $params = ['id' => 'a', 'name' = 'ken']
foreach ($params as $key => $val) {
  $query->where($key, "=", $val);
}
```

However, I cannot find a way for the following complicated query. How can I build a query?

```
((Key1=A and Key2=B) or (Key1=B and Key2=A)) and Key3=C
```

I found the way if the query is `(A or B) and (C or D)`

```
$query->where(function($query) use($value1, $value2){
    $query->where('column1', '=', $value1)->orWhere('column2', '=', $value2)
});
$query->where(function($query) use($value3, $value4){
    $query->where('column1', '=', $value3)->orWhere('column2', '=', $value4)
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`where()` and `orWhere()` closures](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#parameter-grouping) like this if you need `((x and y) or (z and v)) and z`

```
Model::where(function ($q) use ($a, $b) {
        $q->where(function($q) use($a, $b){
            $q->where('key1', $a)->where('key2', $b);
        })
        ->orWhere(function($q) use($a, $b){
            $q->where('key1', $b)->where('key2', $a);
        })
    })
    ->where('key3', $c)
    ->get();
```

Comment: I'm sorry for late reply. I got syntax error somehow. I'm struggle to fix it.